# How to return a custom error message for MaxUploadSizeExceededException?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot application (running with Spring Boot v3.0.5, Spring v6.0.7) where I want to limit the size of file uploads and return a custom error message when the limit is exceeded. I have set the maximum file size in my application.properties file:

```
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=1MB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=1MB
```

And I have created a @ControllerAdvice class to handle MaxUploadSizeExceededException and return a custom error message:

```java
@ControllerAdvice
public class FileUploadExceptionAdvice {

    @ExceptionHandler(MaxUploadSizeExceededException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<String> handleMaxUploadSizeExceededException(MaxUploadSizeExceededException exc) {
        return ResponseEntity
                .status(HttpStatus.PAYLOAD_TOO_LARGE)
                .body("File upload failed: File too large!");
    }
}
```

However, when I test the file upload with a file that exceeds the size limit, the client receives a "Connection reset by peer" error instead of my custom error message, although the MaxUploadSizeExceededException is correctly logged in the console.

How can I ensure that my custom error message is returned to the client when the file size limit is exceeded?

Answer (score 1):

In cases where the client exceeds the file size limit, it might choose to terminate the connection without waiting for a response, which is why your custom error message isn't reaching the client. Rather than closing the connection immediately, your client should be designed to process this status code as a valid server response.

You should modify your client application's code (e.g., a web browser, a mobile app, or any software making HTTP requests to your Spring Boot server) to handle the HTTP 413 Payload Too Large status code as returned by your Spring Boot server when the file size limit is exceeded.

If you need more help on that, please make sure to provide the client side code aswell.

Comment: I believe there is a misunderstanding. My app is not the client; it provides a REST endpoint for uploading files. My goal is to provide a meaningful response to all clients when the file upload limit is exceeded. I have no control over the clients that are uploading files to my app.

Comment: The "Connection reset by peer" error you mentioned earlier says that the client is experiencing a network-level issue before it can receive your custom error message. My guess was a client-side timeout. You should start by figuring out which side is resetting the connection. Is it being closed on the server or the client side? After that you can act accordingly. I've already suggested a solution for the case of connection being closed prematurely from client.

Comment: M.Pour may be can answer on similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77880828/how-to-return-response-after-exception-maxuploadsizeexceededexception

Answer (score 0):

had similar issue and in our case the issue was with scanBasePackages. Due to configuration issue, the Application was not able to locate the ControllerAdvice class and as a result it wrote only log entry and thrown the original error.

After correcting the scanBasePackages, the application was able to locate the  ControllerAdvice class ans thrown custome error message.

Comment: Could you provide more details in your answer? I believe that when the log message is written, the exception handler (and the ControllerAdvice) is engaged. Or perhaps I am mistaken?