# How to return response after exception MaxUploadSizeExceededException

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, rest, tomcat

I have app with reactJS as a client and spring boot as a server.
I try to upload file with big size I catch error on server but didn't get any response on client.

It my client part:

```
  const uploadHandler = async () => {
    if (!acceptedFiles?.length) {
      return;
    }
    setIsLoading(true);

    const formData = new FormData();
    for (let i = 0; i < acceptedFiles.length; i++) {
      formData.append('files', new File([acceptedFiles[i]], parentDir + acceptedFiles[i].name));
    }

    await fetch(`/api/filemanager/${encodeURIComponent(filemanager)}/files`, {
      method: 'POST',
      body: formData,
    })
      .then((response) => {
        setIsLoading(false);
        if (response.ok) {
          return response;
        } else {
          throw new Error(`Request failed with status: ${response.status}, and message: ${response.statusText}`);
        }
      })
      .then(() => {
        onComplete();
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        setIsLoading(false);
      });
  };
```

I catch the error here and return my custom error message:

```
@RestControllerAdvice
public class AdviceController {
    @ExceptionHandler(MaxUploadSizeExceededException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<String> handleMaxUploadSizeExceededException(MaxUploadSizeExceededException exc) {
        return ResponseEntity
            .status(HttpStatus.PAYLOAD_TOO_LARGE)
            .body("File upload failed: File too large!");
    }
}
```

But in browser I doesn't see any response:

[image]

With small size files the app works fine.

Also using postman I see correct answer:

[image]